# How to use datetime in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm writing some code for newsletter using codeigniter, but while trying to input my datetime value into the database, i keep getting '0000-00-00 00:00:00' as the datetime value, could anyone point me in the right direction

I've checked similar topics, but none seem to work for me

Here's the faulty code

```
<?php 
class Process extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function add_quotes($str)
    {
        return "'".$str."'";
    }

     function newsletter_user($log_data)
    {
        $this->load->helper('date');
        date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Lagos'); # add your city to set local time zone
        $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT email FROM newsletter WHERE email ='. $this->add_quotes($log_data['email']));
        if (!empty($query->result()))
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata('error', 'This email is already registered');
        }
        else {

            $this->db->query('INSERT INTO newsletter (first_name, last_name, email, date_subscribe) VALUES ('.$this->add_quotes($log_data['firstname']).', '.$this->add_quotes($log_data['lastname']).', '.$this->add_quotes($log_data['email']).', '.$this->add_quotes($log_data[date('Y-m-d H:i:s')]).')');
            $this->session->set_userdata('error', 'Registration successful! You would be notified once we launch');
        }
        //return $query;
    }


}
?>
```

Comment: I don't see where your variable `$now` is being used, but it would probably be better to have let mysql fill in the date automatically anyway, using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as the default value.

Comment: Also, I recommend using parameterized queries rather than the `add_quotes` method - the escaping of the values will be much safer, and your code will be easier to read.

Comment: @Jerry i replaced $now with date('Y-m-d H:i:s');, its the same thing and also, I've been told timestamp doesn't work for DATETIME

Comment: @Jerry please what do you mean by parameterized queries

Comment: I should have said "query bindings" - https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#query-bindings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out $log_data was causing the issue

it can be solved by removing '$log_data', either this way;

```
$this->db->query('INSERT INTO newsletter (first_name, last_name, email, date_subscribe) VALUES ('.$this->add_quotes($log_data['firstname']).', '.$this->add_quotes($log_data['lastname']).', '.$this->add_quotes($log_data['email']).', '.$this->add_quotes($now).')');
```

or

```
$this->db->query('INSERT INTO newsletter (first_name, last_name, email, date_subscribe) VALUES ('.$this->add_quotes($log_data['firstname']).', '.$this->add_quotes($log_data['lastname']).', '.$this->add_quotes($log_data['email']).', '.$this->add_quotes(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')).')');
```

4 days for a silly mistake!